# Create a variable from function parameter

Tags: javascript

I want to create new variable from these function parameter. How can it be done?

```
function addNewStudent(firstName,lastName){
var firstName+lastName = new Student();
}

addNewStudent('Hero','Man');
```

Error Msg:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

Comment: Doing this with an array or an object literal (or `Map` or `Set`) would be much easier. While it’s more or less possible with a variable (using `eval`), it’s bad practice.

Comment: Looks like you need something like this `new Student(firstName, lastName)` instead.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?  The attempt doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a dynamic variable requires `eval`. This is bad practise. There are better alternatives:

Using an object:

```
var students={};

function addNewStudent(firstName,lastName){
  students[firstName+lastName] = new Student(firstName,lastName);
}

addNewStudent('Hero','Man');

students['HeroMan']; // Student instance
students.HeroMan; // Student instance
```

Using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (only supported with [ES6](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Map)):

```
var students=new Map();

function addNewStudent(firstName,lastName){
  students.add(firstName+lastName, new Student(firstName,lastName));
}

addNewStudent('Hero','Man');

students.get('HeroMan'); // Student instance
```

With the object or the map, you could even get the whole list by accessing `students`. Isn’t that much more convenient and sensible?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a solution as suggested by @dfsq above:

```
function Student(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

var student1 = new Student('Jane', 'Doe');
var student2 = new Student('John', 'Smith');

console.log(student1.firstName, student1.lastName);
console.log(student2.firstName, student2.lastName);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8m7351fq/

But if you must do it the way that you specify above:

```
var students = {};

function addNewStudent(firstName,lastName){
    students[firstName+lastName] = 'Some random data';
}

addNewStudent('Hero','Man');
console.log(students);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/em1ngm2t/1/